# How to pass json array and its object and keys of object in flutter.?

Tags: json, api, parsing, flutter

[enter image description here][1]I want to parse json Array and its object and keys in object of array.? how can i parse.?

```
http.Response response=await http.get("api url");
   List resJson=json.decode(response.body);
   Map decode=jsonDecode(response.body);
   List<Task> task =new List<Task>();
   for(var task in decode['rows']){
    print(task['Task']);
   }
```

i want to parse this array..

"rows":[
      {
         "Task"
               {
                 "title":"aamir"
      },"Category Type":{
                            id:"123"  }
      {
         "number":3,
         "word":"SES"
      }
   ]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you have added isn't valid

If this is the JSON you want to parse -

```
{
    "rows": [{
        "Task": {
            "title": "aamir"
        },
        "Category Type": {
            "id": "123"
        }
    }]
}
```

You can parse it like this -

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < rows.length ; i++) {
  var task = rows[i]["Task"];
  String title = task["title"];
  String id = rows[i]["Category Type"]["id"];
```

Comment: how can i get "rows".?

Comment: `var respBody = jsonDecode(response?.body); var rows = respBody["rows"];`

Comment: If your problem is solved, I would suggest you to mark the answer which helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is good enough for this case but not optimal it would be more efficient if you create a podo (or pojo) then add this method to the podo class (let's say its name is Task).

```
factory Task.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Post(
        title: json["title"];}
```

with a constructor.

```
Task({this.title})
```

And there is a lot of tools as well to create this podo online (ex https://app.quicktype.io) then you decode it like that

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
Iterable<dynamic> l = map["rows"];
List<Task> tasks= l.map((model) => Task.fromJson(model)).toList();
```

and then you have a list of tasks.